# knockout not updating values in view

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I have the following markup:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: nameList">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addname">add name</button>
Total names: <span data-bind="text: nameList().length"></span>
```

My viewmodel looks like this:

```
var viewmodel = {
    nameList: ko.observableArray(["Brian"]),
    number: ko.observable(100),
    addname: function(){
        alert(this.nameList().length);
        this.nameList().push("name");
        alert(this.nameList().length);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

Whenver the addname method is executed, alert updates the nameList array, but
the markup doesn't reflect these changes. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Got it! You need to change:

```
this.nameList().push("name");
```

To this:

```
this.nameList.push("name");
```

(Because `nameList` is an array, not a method)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G464V/